# Yii2- ArrayHelper change index of array

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have an array as follows:

```
[
    0 => [
        'name' => 'CARD'
        'id' => '0'
    ]
    1 => [
        'name' => 'MOBILE'
        'id' => '1'
    ]
    2 => [
        'name' => 'GIFT'
        'id' => '2'
    ]
]
```

I want to change the key **id** to **type** in all the array. Is there a way to do this in Yii2 using ArrayHelper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getColumn()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper#getColumn()-detail) for this:

```
$result = ArrayHelper::getColumn($array, function ($data) {
    return [
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'type' => $data['id'],
    ];
});
```

But it will not really differ from `array_map()` or simple `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an array helper for this but you could do this with a php foreach

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
  $myArray[$key]['type'] = $value['id'];
  unset($myArray[$key]['id']); 
}
```